# ERROR: Parser error: syntax error in file

Tags: openscad

I a newb to OSC.
I know that there is a syntax error relating to the definitions of the variables, but I can't for the life of me fix it.

```
// Define tube dimensions
tube_length = 60;
outer_diameter = 4.5;
rim_thickness = 1;
tube_spacing = 20;

// Define inner diameter
inner_diameter = outer_diameter - 2*rim_thickness;

// Create the tube using a hull and cylinder
tube = hull() {
  cylinder(h = tube_length, r = outer_diameter/2);
  translate([0,0,-rim_thickness]) cylinder(h = tube_length+2*rim_thickness, r = inner_diameter/2);
};

// Create the connector
connector = difference() {
  cylinder(h = rim_thickness, r = outer_diameter/2);
  cylinder(h = rim_thickness, r = inner_diameter/2);
};

// Combine the tubes and connector
tubes_with_connector = union() {
  tubes;
  translate([0, 0, -rim_thickness]) connector;
};
```

I am just trying to create two tubes connected at one end.
I tried removing the semicolons at the end of each statement, but this didn't work.

Comment: Where did you get this syntax from? Assigning geometry to variables may be possible at some point, but right now that's not even supported by the development snapshots.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [modules](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/User-Defined_Functions_and_Modules#Object_modules), then your code should look like this:

```
// Define tube dimensions
tube_length = 60;
outer_diameter = 4.5;
rim_thickness = 1;
tube_spacing = 20;

// Define inner diameter
inner_diameter = outer_diameter - 2*rim_thickness;

// 1.create the elements as module with the necessary variables 

module tube(tl, od, rt, id) {
    hull() {
        cylinder( h = tl, r = od);
        translate([0, 0, -rt]) cylinder( h = tl + 2*rt, r = id);
    }
}

module connector(rt, od, id) {
    difference() {
        cylinder(h = rt, r = od/2);
        cylinder(h = rt, r = id/2);
    }
}

module tubes_with_connector(tl, rt, od, id) {
    union() {
        tube(tl, od, rt, id);
        translate([0, 0, rt]) connector(rt, od, id);
    }
}

//2. invoke the modules with your parameters

tubes_with_connector(tube_length, rim_thickness, outer_diameter, inner_diameter);

// or have a look to the single elements

// tube(tube_length, outer_diameter, rim_thickness, inner_diameter);
// connector(rim_thickness, outer_diameter, inner_diameter);
```